# What is it called when a language sounds strange to a speaker of another language?

Tags: linguistics

Is there a linguistic term for, for example, certain Russian words sounding strange to the ears of a native English speaker?

Thanks

Comment: I usually describe that as * foreign*

Comment: *Greek & Latin*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In linguistics, this phenomenon is called ***cross-language speech perception***.

> A large amount of research has studied how users of a language perceive foreign speech (referred to as cross-language speech perception) or second-language speech (second-language speech perception). The latter falls within the domain of second language acquisition.
>
> Languages differ in their phonemic inventories. Naturally, this creates difficulties when a foreign language is encountered. For example, if two foreign-language sounds are assimilated to a single mother-tongue category the difference between them will be very difficult to discern.
>
> <sub>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_perception</sub>

Comment: Bonus: [The sounds of language](http://languagesindanger.eu/book-of-knowledge/the-sounds-of-language/)

Comment: More concrete example of the text's example: Japanese has a roughly 'r'-sounding phoneme that is nearly halfway between English's 'r' and 'l', which is why hearing the difference between those is difficult for Japanese speakers.

Answer (score -1):

The best term I can come up with is non-native phoneme.